# How to get the historical data in users Tab

Tags: support, data-explorer, users-page

We are working on preparing the monthly report for [the most active contributor in SharePoint StackExchange](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1474/most-active-contributors-monthly-report-oct-2017) .

One of these statistics for the most editors and voters got it from the Users tab

[image]

Unfortunately, Users Tab show **only** the current week,month,quarter and year.
 and we can't get the historical information from this tab for last year, quarter and month!!

So could you please advise

- How can I get this historical information from User Tab for all users per month, quarter and year?
- Is there any parameters that we can pass it to https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users to get the previous month information

Comment: You mean edits and votes during 2017? (per user)

Comment: No bro, for all users, kindly check my updated question!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Statistics on voters is not possible via SEDE; votes are anonymized before they are made publicly accessible.

Editors *might* be possible. I'm not sure if edits to your own posts count for the 'league', but [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/sharepoint/query/776478/editors-in-december) is based on something that comes very close to the numbers I see for my own account (on other sites). Note that SEDE is refreshed once a week, on Sunday morning, so edits on most of December 31st are not included yet. Congratulations, you're the winner:

[image]

For reference, here is the complete query. Feel free to [fork](https://data.stackexchange.com/sharepoint/query/fork/776478) it if you need the data for the last week / last year instead.

```sql
SELECT UserId AS [User Link], COUNT(*) AS [Number of edits]
FROM

(
SELECT UserId, CreationDate
  FROM PostHistory
  WHERE PostHistoryTypeId IN (4, 5, 6)
    AND CreationDate BETWEEN '2017-12-01' AND '2017-12-31'
  GROUP BY UserId, CreationDate
) AS edits

GROUP BY UserId
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your great answer, Is there any parameters that we can pass it to https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users to get the previous month information

Comment: You're welcome. I thought of a possible solution in that direction as well, but AFAIK those only work for the reputation leagues and not the other activity statistics (e.g. https://stackexchange.com/leagues/105/month/sharepoint/2017-11-01)